# Find biggest possible polygon of group of points

Tags: geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

How to find the biggest possible polygon of a group of points?

E.g. the following points are given:

```
0 | 3
4 | 0
1 | 1
0 | 0
```

-> Use the  1st, 2nd and 4th point to build a polygon (3rd point is useless)

Comment: By biggest, do you mean the largest area?

Comment: Do you look for something like convex hull? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)

Comment: Do you have a specific question about some code that you've written or would you like us to code the problem up for you?

Comment: @Grammin He's asking about an algorithm. He has a problem, and is trying to identify if that problem has a name. It's quite a common issue, because if the problem already has a name, you are going to reinvent the wheel ... Not everything is about coding here ... :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seems to be looking for is the [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

Example:

[image]

The [Gift Wrapping Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) is the easiest way to calculate the Convex Hull, but it isn't optimal.

[Chan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan%27s_algorithm) is probably the simplest optimal algorithm.

HTH!

Comment: That's exactly what Im looking for. Thank you!